# e-1, using Taylor Series

Tags: taylor-expansion

I'm trying to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{2}}{\left(n+1\right)!}=e-1$ using Taylor series, I know that $e=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$ and also that $e-1=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$ but i don't know how to procced.

Answer (score 1):

$e^{x}-1= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {x^{n}} {n!}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {x^{n+1}} {(n+1)!}$. Differentiate twice to get $e^{x}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {(n+1)nx^{n}} {(n+1)!}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {n^{2}x^{n}} {(n+1)!}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {nx^{n}} {(n+1)!}$. Put $x=1$. Can you finish?

[$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac {n} {(n+1)!}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac {n+1} {(n+1)!}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac {1} {(n+1)!}$].

Answer (score 0):

$$e=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}$$
Then $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+1)!}=e-1$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k-1)!}$ as $(-1)!\to \infty$

Now note that  $$S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{(n+1)!}= \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(m-1)^2}{m!}= \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{m^2}{m!}-\frac{2m}{m!} +\frac{1}{m!}\right)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{m}{(m-1)!}-\frac{2}{(m-1)!} +\frac{1}{m!}\right)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{m-1+1}{(m-1)!}-\frac{2}{(m-1)!} +\frac{1}{m!}\right)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{(m-2)!}-\frac{1}{(m-1)!} +\frac{1}{m!}\right)=e-e+(e-1)=e-1$$